# Is there any upper limit on the number of members a sorted set in redis can store?

Tags: redis, sortedset

Is there any upper limit on the number of members a sorted set in redis can store?

For example, according to [this link](https://redis.io/topics/data-types), 2^32 - 1 different members can only be stored in redis set, list. No such upper limit is mentioned for redis sorted set. So should I assume that, the upper limit depends on the memory that is available or there is a fixed number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same limit - 2^32-1 - applies to Redis' Sets and Sorted Sets as well.

An excerpt from the [Data types](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#sets) page at [redis.io](https://redis.io):

> The max number of members in a set is 2<sup>32</sup> - 1 (4294967295, more than 4 billion of members per set).

While not mentioned in that page, both Sets and Sorted Sets use the same underlying data structure (which, in turn, is a hash). Hence, they share the same limit.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you please specify the link which says that so that I can be more confident.

Comment: Edited my reply

Comment: Yes. But it says only for sets and not for sorted sets. This is my concern. It even says for list, hashes separately. But nothing is mentioned for sorted sets.

Comment: Edited more. The documentation isn't perfect (feel free to submit a pull request at https://github.com/antirez/redis-doc), but I'm familiar with the source code (see https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/t_zset.c#L35)

Comment: Is there any other way/data structure in which I can have more 2^32 -1 elements in redis?

Comment: No, but you can have 2^32 keys, each holding 2^32 elements.

Comment: @ItamarHaber I thought Sorted Sets are based on skip list? Also, Sorted Set's time complexity to search a member is O(log n). Hashes are O(1).